# Predefine error message with angular validation custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I am doing angular validation as follows:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="vm.create(vm.job)" validation="vm.errors">
  <input name="vm.job.position" type="text" ng-model="vm.job.position" validator />
```

When the form is submitted the directive gets the name of the property, e.g. position, from the `ng-model`. It then checks if `vm.errors` has a message for that property. If yes then adds a span with the error message after the input.

However, I would also like to use the same directive in another way:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="vm.create(vm.job)" validation="vm.errors">
  <input name="vm.job.position" type="text" ng-model="vm.job.position" />
  <span class="error" validator="position"></span>
```

In this case I removed the validator from the input and added the span already allowing me to control where the error will be displayed. In this case I am using `validator="position"` to define to which model property the error message is associated.

I am not sure how should I add this functionality to my current code ... Any help is appreciated.

The following is all the code I have on my directives:

```
(function () {

  "use strict";

  angular.module("app").directive("validation", validation);

  function validation() {

    var validation = {
      controller: ["$scope", controller],
      replace: false,
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        validation: "="
      }
    };

    return validation;

    function controller($scope) {

      var vm = this;

      $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $scope.validation;
      }, function () {
        vm.errors = $scope.validation;
      })

    }

  }

  angular.module("app").directive("validator", validator);

  function validator() {

    var validator = {
      link: link,
      replace: false,
      require: "^validation",
      restrict: "A"
    };

    return validator;

    function link(scope, element, attributes, controller) {

      scope.$watch(function () {

        return controller.errors;

      }, function () {

        if (controller.errors) {

          var result = controller.errors.filter(function (error) {

            if (error.flag == null)
              return false;

            var position = attributes.name.lastIndexOf(".");

            if (position > -1)
              return attributes.name.slice(position + 1).toLowerCase() === error.flag.toLowerCase();
            else
              return attributes.name.toLowerCase() === error.flag.toLowerCase();

          });

          if (result.length > 0) {

            var error = element.siblings("span.error").first();

            if (error.length == 0)
              element.parent().append("<span class='error'>" + result[0].info + "</span>");
            else
              error.text(result[0].info);

          } else {

            element.siblings("span.error").first().remove();

          } 

        }
      }, true);
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [ngModelController docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)?  The proper way is to have the directive that does validation on the same element as the `ng-model` and use `require: 'ngModel'` to gain access to the `ngModelController`, which you can then add to its `$validators` object.

Comment: Yes, but I am using this directives as I am syncronizing client validation with server validation ... I really need to use this directives.

Comment: there is also the `$asyncValidators` object of `ngModelController` if you need server-side validation.  Also check out [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages) which let's you easily manage error messages. Form validation is really standard suff, I think you might be making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: But if all you're asking is how to translate from having validator directive on the input, to have it on the span itself, then you would simply need to modify the logic in `validator` directive's link function on how it detects where to output the errors.  But really, your `validator` directive looks to be doing this (outputting an error message) the very hard way.